Bluetooth on iMac 17,1 (2015 27'' 5K) sometimes not connected
The Bluetooth on my 2015 27'' 5K iMac (iMac17,1) sometimes is available and working and sometimes doesn't. I may have to restart the PC but sometimes even if I restart it 5 times the Bluetooth is not showing up.
If I try to power it up from the GUI it doesn't do anything and stay grey. If I run lspci I can't see the Bluetooth. I will restart it a couple of more times and eventually will find it and it will work.
WiFi always works. Only Bluetooth doesn't. I have tried UBUNTU 23.10 and 24.04 (otherwise I would not have posted here), Debian, Fedora, Arch (Endeavour) and I always get the same problem.

Ubuntu 23.10 was my first try. I hoped that the release of 24.04 would have helped but nothing has changed

Edit to include results for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
